# Set text color that doesn't change in darkmode

Tags: html, darkmode

I am building an email in HTML and I don't want the text color to change in darkmode. Is there an easy way of doing this? I have put white background images to avoid the background to change.

Comment: What happens if your specify the text color? Dark mode is a feature of the client you read the email with. Which one are you using? Please be precise in your question. What does your HTML look like? Also, don't forget that people intentionally choose dark mode, it's what they want and expect.

Comment: try this
.dark{
  background: #121212;
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
.dark iframe,.dark img,.dark html {
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(105%) contrast(105%);
}

Answer (score 0):

you can change the text color with CSS:

```
<a href = "mailto: abc@example.com" style="color: #252525;">Send Email</a>
```

Comment: that's being overwritten in darkmode though

Comment: you can add !important ```<a href = "mailto: abc@example.com" style="color: #252525 !important;">Send Email</a>```